# CSS3 nth:child number

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my html page. In this case, why the 1st element of p attribute is consider like the 2nd element ?

```css
/* This won't work */
#div1 p:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ff0000;
}

/* This will work */
#div2 p:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34bz28a0/

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `nth-of-type(1)` instead of `nth-child()` since the latter will calculate the order irrespective of the element type.

`p:nth-child(1)` will not work because the paragraph is not the first element of the parent.

```css
p:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When use :nth-child then ?

Comment: If all the elements inside the parent are of the same type, use `nth-child`. If the elements vary, you can make use of `nth-of-type`, although `nth-child` will also work here but will select all the elements irrespective of the tag.

Comment: Or even `first:of-type` :) I don't understand the downvote though.

Answer (score 2):

`nth-child` counts the number of child elements in relation to parent. If you only want to count `p` elements, you should use `nth-of-type`, i.e.

```
p:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

[Your updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34bz28a0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:first-child` pseudo-selector instead.

Try this:

```
#div1 p:first-child {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your selector didn't work when using `p:nth-child(1)` is that the selectors work like and *IF* statement with *AND* between rules that are not separated by some specifier (such as space character or `>`, `~` and so on). For example, the selector `div.myClass` matches `<div>` elements whose class is `myClass`. The same hold for pseudo classes: `div:hover` matches `<div>` elements that are being hovered. In your case, the combination is `p:nth-child(1)` which picks `<p>` elements that have 0 (the formula is *an+b-1*) sibling before it in the document tree, and there are no such elements. With `p:nth-child(2)` you get the 2nd element that is also a `<p>`.

As far as solving this, the most obvious solutions are to either use `:nth-child(2)` to pick the 2nd sibling regardless of type, or `p:nth-of-type(1)`<sup>1</sup> (or simply `p:first-of-type`) to match the 1st element of type `<p>`.

<sup>1</sup> A note about `nth-of-type(an+b)`: this pseudo-class matches elements that are the n<sub>th</sub> of their type, regardless of a leading type selector. See next snippet:

```css
:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>span</span>
<span>span</span>
<span>span</span>
<b>b</b>
<b>b</b>
<b>b</b>
```